# Android: How to get the process id of the foreground app

Tags: android, go

First of all, please note that this question is *not* same as all the "android foreground app" questions I found on SO, please read on :-)

I'm trying to write an android app for my own use, using golang, *without* using android-sdk or ndk (this is the KEY point).  It is pretty simple, just use golang to write a http service, compile it for arm CPU and voila my app is running and can be access by simply visit http://localhost.

For the purpose of my app, I need to know the currently running foreground application, to define it precisely:

1. Foreground application is the application that occupies the screen, or has an "activity" what-so-ever (forgive me I'm not an android developer).
2. Anything that that is depended by the foreground application (e.g. services) is NOT what I am interested in.
3. If the phone is LOCKED/screen turned off, I want the solution to tell me there is NO foreground app.

And since I do not use anything android, just treat the phone as a LINUX machine, I want the solution to use native LINUX ways, e.g. by inspect /proc, or by calling any installed android command line tool (including sending messages via these command line tools), but **NOT** using any SDK/NDK way so that I have to use java or incorporate these thing into my app.

Comment: "foreground application is the application that occupies the screen" -- there can be more than one "foreground application", by your definition. "I want the solution to use native linux ways" -- most things in Android cannot be accomplished by "native linux ways".

Comment: @CommonsWare OK, to be more precise, I want the app that takes FULL screen, not that some widget that shows the weather info...  I can even accept solutions that is NOT accurate, e.g. if an application has a higher priority can be reasonably "guessed" as being foreground, I can accept that solution, anything that does not rely on android-sdk is a candidate.  To clarify my purpose, I am writing an application that kills background application, or any application that is started without my consent.

Comment: to clarify my purpose, I want to write a service runs in background that kills any application launched without my consent, so I just want to avoid kill an application while I am using it.

Comment: "I want the app that takes FULL screen, not that some widget that shows the weather info" -- I was referring to multi-window (added to all phones and tablets with Android 7.0, plus some manufacturer-specific solutions before then). "I want to write a service runs in background that kills any application launched without my consent, so I just want to avoid kill an application while I am using it" -- that's an odd use of an HTTP daemon. Regardless, unless your device is old, rooted, or both, it would be difficult to do this *with* the SDK, let alone without it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tested and unfortunately my idea requires root privilege... however, if I get root, I still think this is workable... as regarding http, I just try to use that to write a control UI, not in the focus of the whole idea.

Comment: I guess an android app is aware of its focus (much like web api does), using that this app can tell the background which focus state it has. but it is client dependant.

Comment: Do you have ADB access? Or better, root? Remember you can actually do a self-connection via ADB-WiFi on loopback, so if the device has at least Android 11, it can be done with minimal user interaction once per reboot.

Comment: Also, do you mind spawning an ART subprocess to run Java code as a subprocess of your Go app?

Comment: You can not kill other apps without having a native app of yourself on the device, and for that, you are going to need to work with services in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Android SDK 26 (if I remember well) Apps are executed on -one-User-per-App, so (i.e.) WhatsApp is running on UID=30 and Telegram on UID=76, so executing a ROOT command of "ps -A -o PID,USER,NAME" you can parse output and then Kill all Processes that you don't want to be executed.

```
36119 u30_a149     <WhatsApp_packagename>
36203 u76_a211     <Telegram_packagename>
37399 root         [kworker/1:2H]
37423 u0_a329      su
38069 root         sh
```

Without Root Permissions nothing of what you're trying to achieve is possible simply because is not possibile to denied an application to be executed or to kill it without Superuser privilege.